# Is it possible to have ENUM with zero elements

Tags: java, enums

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface DatabaseTable {

    public void onDatabaseCreate(SQLiteDatabase database);

    public void onDatabaseUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion);

    public String getName();

    public Column[] getColumns();

    public int insert(SQLiteDatabase database, ContentValues values);

    public int delete(SQLiteDatabase database, String selection, String[] selectionArgs);

    public static interface Column {

        public String getName();

        public String getType();
    }
}
```

I know that Enums can implement interfaces. If I was to implement this interface as Enum, I would have to use it as if it was Enum singleton (`DatabaseTableImpl.INSTANCE.getName()`). Can I have a zero-element Enum so that it could be implemented and used like a class consisting only of static methods (`DatabaseTableImpl.getName()`)?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Your compiler is a 100% reliable source of answers on questions like this, with a delay of about 30 seconds. Asking here instead isn't really a rational discovery procedure.

Comment: If you want enum singleton, then you need one-element enum, not zero-element.

Comment: Why would you want to write the interface as an `enum`?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are trying to be too clever and failing to observer the KISS principle.

Comment: just for making it singleton- are you thinking of making it as enum. There is no point in doing this with enum

Comment: Well normal class can't implement static methods. That's the whole point. 
And yes, I have tried it. It's possible to just write ";" instead of an element name, but then "NAME" is automatically assumed to be the element name. I'm wondering if there are any tricks to do that, why would you think that it's irrational "discovery procedure" to ask such thing on SO?

Comment: @Julius B. 'Normal class can't implement static methods' is meaningless. Static methods can't be defined in such a way that they need to be implemented, but a 'normal class' can certainly *define* static methods. You aren't making much sense here, and you are still wasting time rather than consulting your compiler.

Comment: Show a minimal amount of Effort please. How many seconds does it take to type `enum Foo { }`... ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you use "implement". I wrote a "normal" class yesterday that uses a static method to achieve some of its goals so...

Comment: @Julius B.: “but then "NAME" is automatically assumed to be the element name”— not with the Java *we* know.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have ENUM with zero elements

Yes. You could always have *tried* it yourself, instead of wasting time asking here.

> If I was to implement this interface as Enum

You can't. A class can't be both an interface and an `enum.`

The relation between this question and the previous one escapes me.

> I would have to use it as if it was Enum singleton

This is meaningless to me.

> Can I have a zero-element Enum so that it could be implemented and used like a class consisting only of static methods

Again, why not *try* it? Not that I understand how it's going to solve your actual problem, whatever that is.